# cut function with breaks and labels gives "rm.paranthesis" error

Tags: r

When I was trying to quickly discretise a continuous variable with `cut`, I started getting a very odd error that I cannot find any documentation for.

```r
quakes$depth_factor <-  cut(quakes$depth, breaks = c(-Inf, 50, 100, 500, Inf),
                     labels = c("50 m or less", "51-100 m", "99-500 m", "501 m or more"))

Warning messages:
1: In rm.paranthesis(x1) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In rm.paranthesis(x2) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Everything else was working fine, but when I restarted R, the issue went away... so I don't know if this will be reproducible for anyone. I just spent a good while trying to figure this weird error (with a typo?).

Is this a sign that something has broken in the R interpreter and restarting the session is compulsory?

Comment: May be you had another function with the same name from a different packge in the previous session and it masked

Comment: Thanks akrun.... rookie mistake... One of my functions `require` d "raster", which does have a `cut` function. I just didn't even know I had loaded it... and couldn't find any info on that error!

Comment: This happens even when you load dplyr along with plyr and summarise/mutate etc. gets messed up